# Similarities between Babbage's difference engine and the Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines, computation-models, history

What would you consider similarities between the difference engine and the Turing machine? At this point I feel I know how they both function, yet I can't point out any worthwhile similarities between the two. And how do these two relate to modern phones? Other than the first two being milestones of computational science. I have this task as an assignment.

Comment: Modern computers use the von Neumann architecture. Both of your models are of purely theoretical interest.